# Select Property to display Highlighted Content Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I am using the Highlighted Content Web Part.
I want to customise my result view and select a specified properties to display from the item found in the search query.

[image]

I want to change the view from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

**Question:** How can I perform that ? How can I select or filter the viewed properties ?

Comment: Are you showing any specific document library or anything else?

Comment: items from similar lists